# Android define custom style for Menu item

Tags: android, styles, themes

I want to customize text style Android menu item.
I put this to styles.xml

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/my_custome_actionbar_menu_item</item>
```

It does not work, but when I remove "android:", it work properly

```
<item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/my_custome_actionbar_menu_item </item>
```

Do you know What is different between having "android: " and not?

Comment: Do you want to view custom view in action menu?

Answer (score 0):

if you use api7-13,use `actionMenuTextAppearance`,and if your sdk api>17,use `android:actionMenuTextAppearance`,maybe the sdk you are using is lower than 17.

Comment: I use api-21 not <17

Comment: I mean the sdk your device uses.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the reason about AppCompat

> With new AppCompat-v7 (v21) ActionBar style's properties need to refer to the app namespace, that is without android: prefix.

So,for retro-compatibility, we should use actionBarStyle along with android:actionBarStyle: